# ggplot2 spacing of y values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a plot in ggplot2.  Here are the data, named problem_accept_df:

```
Order Application probscore
1  Integrated 0.8333333
1      Tabbed 0.7777778
2  Integrated 0.8965517
2      Tabbed 0.7777778
3  Integrated 0.7931034
3      Tabbed 0.7777778
4  Integrated       0.7
4      Tabbed 0.6538462
5  Integrated 0.9285714
5      Tabbed 0.8333333
6  Integrated 0.9310345
6      Tabbed 0.8148148
7  Integrated 0.8571429
7      Tabbed 0.8518519
8  Integrated 0.9333333
8      Tabbed 0.6923077
9  Integrated 0.9310345
9      Tabbed 0.8461538
10  Integrated 0.9285714
10      Tabbed       0.8
```

And here is the code to create the plot:

```
ggplot(problem_accept_df, aes(x=Order, y=probscore, color=Application,
group=Application)) + 
xlab('Order') +
ylab('Problem scores') +
geom_line(position=pd, size=2) +
geom_point(position=pd, size=4) +
labs(title='Acceptable proportion of problem scores')
```

The plot is created, but the y values are displayed on equally spaced tick marks even though the values are not equally spaced.  The plot also displays every individual y value instead of a range.  I've tried to change that (`scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0.5, 1, 0.1))`) but I get the error message `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` so the problem must be more basic.  I would appreciate any suggestions about what to do.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if the data (in your case `probscore`) is a factor and not a continuous variable.

```
> d <- data.frame(x=c(0,1), y=factor(c(0.5, 1.5)))
> d
  x   y
1 0 0.5
2 1 1.5
> levels(d$x)
NULL
> levels(d$y)
[1] "0.5" "1.5"
> library(ggplot2)
> ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + scale_y_continuous()
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
> ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=as.numeric(as.character(y)))) + geom_point() + scale_y_continuous()
```

Comment: Thanks--this fixes the spacing but now it plots the values incorrectly.  Better stick with qplot, I guess.

Comment: I mean the points are in the wrong places.  The final value for "Tabbed", for example, is 0.8, but the point appears at 0.85.

Comment: `ggplot` plot what it finds in the data. What does `as.numeric(as.character(problem_accept_df$probscore))` look like?

Comment: `as.numeric(as.character(problem_accept_df$probscore))` looks like the final column of the dataset, which is what I would expect.  The last value is 0.80000000.

Comment: @user1895691: Please ask a separate question for this issue. I'm not sure that I understand it correctly from the comments, and other users might provide input, too. For better understanding of the problem you can also fix the data in the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks--was going to ask another question but found that instead of `ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=as.numeric(as.character(y)))) + . . .` I needed `ggplot(d, aes(x=sort(x), y=as.numeric(as.character(y)))) +`.